ghcr.io - Network is unreachable
I am trying to download the homepage dashboard using Docker:
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /path/to/config:/app/config -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ghcr.io/gethomepage/homepage:latest

But I get this output:
Unable to find image 'ghcr.io/gethomepage/homepage:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": dial tcp 140.82.121.34:443: connect: network is unreachable.
See 'docker run --help'.

So, I tried:
ping ghcr.io

Which does not work, showing that the network is unreachable.
I also tried ping google.com, which does work, showing that I still have some internet connexion.
Here is my ifconfig:
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:ceff:fed9:d3bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:ce:d9:d3:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 76  bytes 4360 (4.2 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 47  bytes 4862 (4.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 2001:861:3dc1:2660:223:24ff:febc:89d7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:febc:89d7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:23:24:bc:89:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 9018  bytes 963609 (941.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 3713  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3426  bytes 432387 (422.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf000000-df020000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth02152d0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::e42f:e2ff:fe8a:a94b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether e6:2f:e2:8a:a9:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 39  bytes 2786 (2.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 36  bytes 3354 (3.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Can you help me solve this problem ?

I ran into the same issue on a Hetzner IPv6 only machine. The reason for the error seems to be, that ghcr.io does not provide an IPv6 AAAA DNS record. There is an open issue from November 2023 mentioning it.
I personally solved the issue by using a different image registry, in my case DockerHub, which allows to freely host public images.
